# Command ValidateEmbeddedBinary failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: macos, xcode12

I ran into this error after upgrading `xCode` to version `12.4`
[image: Error output]

Build fails with the following message:

> "Command ValidateEmbeddedBinary failed with a nonzero exit code"

This error concerns the validation of the extension to the macOS application (in this case, `NetworkExtention`)

Answer (score 4):

After more than 2 days of research, I found out that the error was caused by the following code in my Info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleSupportedPlatforms</key>
<string>MacOSX</string>
```

After deleting this piece of code, the error disappeared.
I hope this helps someone avoid wasting time.)

Comment: that sounds lik a good suggestion but Xcode just re-adds this automatically.

unable to build anything with 12.4

Comment: I don't even have that Key and I'm getting the same error :(